# Server.Transfer losing local variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For my application, I have a page that redirects to another page (within the same application) via `Server.Transfer`. I need to do this because the original page has an object that I need to access by using the `Page.PreviousPage` property.

Once my "destination" page has been fully loaded, a local deep clone that I made of the source page's object is suddenly released from memory once I perform a postback? Is this by design--something to do with the Server.Transfer?

An example...

**Page1.aspx:**

```
Public Structure myCustomObject
    Implements ICloneable
    Dim someField as String = "default value" ' Default value
    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements System.ICloneable.Clone
        Dim temp as new myCustomObject
        temp.someField = Me.someField
        Return temp
    End Function
End Structure

Dim obj As myCustomObject
Public ReadOnly Property objProp as myCustomObject
    Get
        Return obj
    End Get
End Property
objProp.someField = "changed value from source page"

Server.Transfer("page2.aspx", True)
```

---

**Page2.aspx:**

```
(onLoad)
Dim newObj As myCustomObject
newObj = Page.PreviousPage.objProp.Clone()
Debug.Write(newObj.someField) ' Output: "changed value from source page"
```

At this point, EVERYTHING works as it should. Stuff got cloned over correctly and all is well.

```
(Let's say this is on a button click event)
Debug.Write(newObj.someField) ' Output: "default value"<- This is NOT "changed value from source page" for some reason when it was working literally a few lines ago!
```

It's around here that I get the problem. My guess is that the Server.Transfer stops any association with the source page after the new page loads.

Is there a better way for cross-page object passing?

Comment: if you put a button and a server side click on that page can you access your object from the click event? can you show some code?

Comment: What I said might be slightly unclear, but I don't know any other way to put it.

Comment: This smells bad to me. Surely you could store the original object in some other container and pull it back out in the re-directed page's page load?

Comment: @Graham I think that's the catch. I'm not sure what "container" is best for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a variable in the `HttpContext`, you will have to handle your casting, not sure what `Page.PreviousPage` is:

**Current Page:**

```
HttpContext CurrContext = HttpContext.Current;
CurrContext.Items.Add("PreviousPage", Page.PreviousPage);
```

**Transfered to page:**

```
HttpContext CurrContext = HttpContext.Current;
var previousPage = CurrContext.Items["PreviousPage"];
```

Sorry for the C#, there was no code and the question wasn't marked with VB.NET when I answered.  Someone feel free to convert.

Comment: Does this work with objects? Won't I need to serialize if I go this route?

Comment: Server.Transfer isn't a new request, you are still on the server, no need to serialize.  HttpContext.Items is just a Dictionary.

Comment: I just tested your method, and it's giving me the same result as my example. Somehow, when I perform a postback, the HttpContext.Current at the Transferred To Page has no recollection of what I added from the Current Page.

Comment: Try passing a string test value "foo", is it gone?

Comment: Yes. No idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for the solution to this issue, it's more than likely the `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;` setting in your `RouteConfig.cs`.  Change it to `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;`

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //  settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
```